# CSS3 : Fade in on hover and Fade out when hover is gone

Tags: html, css, fadein, fadeout

I have a div. When I hover on it , it should be appeared using fadeIn effect and when I remove mouse then it should gone using fadeOut effect.

I have tried the below code.

```css
.main_div{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:thin black solid;
position:relative;

}

.main_div .overlay_div{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:none;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
transition-duration: 100ms;
transition-delay: 1s;
    
-ms-transition: opacity;
-ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-ms-transition-duration: 100ms;
-ms-transition-delay: 1s; 
    
-moz-transition: opacity;
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-moz-transition-duration: 100ms;
-moz-transition-delay: 1s; 
    
-webkit-transition: opacity;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 100ms;
-webkit-transition-delay: 1s;    


}

.main_div:hover .overlay_div{
display:block;

opacity: 1;

/* Fade in */
transition: opacity;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
transition-duration: 100ms;

-ms-transition:opacity;
-ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-ms-transition-duration: 100ms;

-moz-transition:opacity;
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-moz-transition-duration: 100ms;

-webkit-transition: opacity;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 100ms;

}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="overlay_div">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CSS Transitions don't work on `display:block/none;` You can manage to give that effect using `visibility/opacity` properties.

Check this example, You can manually add the `transition-delay` property if you really want it to add.

```css
.main_div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: thin black solid;
  position: relative;
}

.main_div .overlay_div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.main_div:hover .overlay_div {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="overlay_div">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use both? One property is just fine. And in the hover portion you can remove the transition and it still works (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_buttons_fade1)

Comment: it works! but I was changing the animation effects. That is it. no other reason. 
If the property is applied on the default state of the selector, it will work in both

Answer (score 0):

Code work fine just change display from `none` to `block`, as transition doesn't works when changing `display`.

```
.main_div .overlay_div{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;/*Change this*/
......
......
}
```